# Using a variable for the value of size attribute in <select ..> (HTML, PHP, SQL)

Tags: php, sql, html-select

I'm trying to make a drop-down menu using select. The contents are names from a database. I want the size of the select to be the ammount of entries in my table *tickets*.

I want the size of

```
echo '<select name="Tickets" size=5>'; //this works fine, but I want the size to be relative
```

to be a variable instead of the constant value of 5. So far, I've tried this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets order by ID");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

//echo $numrows; Was just testing to see if it got the right number (it did).

echo '<select name="Tickets" size=$numrows>';
```

but that doesn't seem to work. How do I achieve this? Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't echo out a variable in `'`, it needs to be `"`.

So you can re-write it as this:

```
echo "<select name='Tickets' size=$numrows>";
```

Or this:

```
echo '<select name="Tickets" size='.$numrows.'>';
```

Comment: No worries glad I could help @Whims :)